# How to count the amount of data in a column?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a function to count registered users, but when using this function, an error appears:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Executable SQL or text() construct expected, got <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.FunctionFilter object at 0x7ff409686950>.

here is my code:

```
async def count_registration_status():
    _session_maker: sessionmaker = session_maker
    async with _session_maker() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            result = await session.execute(func.count(User.registration_status).filter(text('Зарегистрирован')))
    return result.scalar()
```

Answer (score 0):

A function call cannot be filtered directly, it must be wrapped by a `select`:

```py
session.execute(
    select(func.count(User.registration_status)).filter(text('Зарегистрирован'))
)
```